# Larger p-values but less misclassification error in Logistic Regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, modeling

I was doing logistic regression in R on 'Smarket' data set available in the ISLR library.
Since correlation between variables were less, I used all variables in my model and I was getting the following result

[image: Logistic Regression Output]

Here p -values are greater then 0.05 for all the variables.

Then I checked the misclassification error and the error was almost zero.

[image: Misclassification Output]

I have tried removing some variables. But still the p values are greater than 0.05 and the misclassification error rates are high for those models.

Can I use this model ??
Is p-value insignificant in logistic regression?

Comment: Did you train on the same data you tested on? If so you should try [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29). In any case, if you provided the data and a [reproducible version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it would help in answering.

Comment: @David: OP did, saying it is in the ISLR package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem, and it comes down to basic arithmetic: you are modeling *Direction*, which is a binary variable (Up or Down), and your independent variables define it perfectly.

Direction=Up where Today>Lag1
Direction=Down where Today

The arithmetic in your model shows you the mistake:
Direction=Today+Lag1+....

Essentially, because the definition of Direction is built in to the formula, you have for many cases a tautology: price (I assume that's what it is) increases because it increases.

The p-values are high because I suspect (though I don't know for sure) that glm (if that's what you're using, you don't say) is excluding the perfect predictions from the results. According to my output:

```
glm(Direction~Lag1+Lag2+Lag3+Lag4+Lag5+Volume+Today,data=Smarket,family="binomial")
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Even if you ignore those pretty important warnings, your table should also give you pause. There are 1250 rows in Smarket; your 2x2 table only has 252.

Comment: I did split my data to training and testing data. 252 was the size of my testing data.

Comment: OK, thanks - next time you may want to state that in your original post. At CV the more information on the context and the procedures you followed, the more likely you will get a timely and accurate answer. Welcome!

Comment: +1, note however that `glm()` doesn't exclude perfect predictions, rather the optimization search algorithm is looking for where the likelihood function turns over. But it never does, so it just keeps going further & further as the likelihood keeps going up (down) but by less & less. When the change is less than some threshold, it stops; that's the coefficient estimate. The Wald SEs are based on the curvature at that point, but it's very flat there, so they are very wide. The p's are high b/c the SEs are wide. Your point about the table is a good one, though; it may not be `glm()`.